# TeamCity: How to add build statistic after building process is finished

Tags: teamcity

The aim is to add some new statistic to a TeamCity build after it had been created, in order to be able to create a chart to see how certain parameters change from one build to another.

The key point is that I cannot integrate this logic into build script as it will increase the build time significantly, so I have to add the entries after that.

I've investigated API tried to find some workarounds, but of no use.

I appreciate any help.

TC version `TeamCity Professional 2017.2 EAP (build 49391)`

Thanks!